# TFS: can't undo/delete branched project

Tags: tfs

I branched a project as a test, but now I can't undo the change or delete the test project.
What I did:

1. Right clicked on a project and selected "Branching and Merging | Branch".
2. Gave the new branch a new "test".
3. Clicked OK.
4. A test project shows on the TFS projects tree.

Now I want to undo or delete the test project. But nothing seems to work:

1. Undo pending changes: I tried on both the original and test projects. In both, I get a message "There are no changes to undo".
2. Delete the test project - the "Delete" option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

"Get Latest" on the test project. Then Delete is allowed.